# How to reverse the text data in the ctl file using python horizontally and save it in new file?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

**I have a ctl file consist of text  as shown below

mycnf_001/mycnf_001_001 
mycnf_001/mycnf_001_002
.......................
....................... (a very long list consist of 1000 lines)

I am trying hard but I am not able to get my desired format

mycnf_001_001 mycnf_001
mycnf_001_002 mycnf_001
.......................
....................... (a very long list consist of 1000 lines)

********* DETAILED PROBLEM DESCRIPTION***************************

CURRENT FORMAT      mycnf_001/mycnf_001_001

DESIRED FROMAT      mycnf_001_001 mycnf_001

////////////CODE/////////////////////

```
f = open("ms.ctl", "rb")
s = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newms.ctl", "wb")
s.reverse()
for item in s:
  print>>f, item
f.close()
```

When I execute the above code then it simply reverses the order from bottom to top and what I need is clearly mentioned above.

Comment: Stp-1 Current format     mycnf_001/mycnf_001_001   Stp-2 simply twist the txt data with ref to the slash (/) mycnf_001_001/mycnf_001  Stp-3 and                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             then del the (/) make spc in b/w the txt.  mycnf_001_001 mycnf_001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume after reading file "ms.ctl" you have value like

```
s="mycnf_001/mycnf_001_001/mycnf_001_002"
```

Now split the string with respect to '/'

```
spliteds = [x for x in s.split('/') if x.strip()]
```

Now you have array of strings. Now try to access the array and from last and save it in another string.

```
desireds=""
for i in reversed(spliteds):
        desireds = desireds + i + " "
```

Now you can put this string in any file.

CODE:

```
    f = open("ms.ctl", "rb")
    s = f.read()
    f.close()

    N = s.split('\n')

    f = open("newms.ctl", "wb")

    spliteds = [ x for x in N[0].split('/') if x.strip()]
    desireds=""
    for i in reversed(spliteds):
            desireds = desireds + i + " "
    #print desireds

    f.write(desireds)
    f.close()
```

You can debug this code using print. Hope it helps.

> UPDATE

**If you want to run it for more than one lines.**

```
f = open("ms.ctl", "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()

N = s.split('\n')
lenth = len(N)

f = open("newms.ctl", "wb")

for x in range(0, lenth):
        print "We're on time %d" % (x)
        spliteds = [ x for x in N[0].split('/') if x.strip()]
        desireds=""
        for i in reversed(spliteds):
                desireds = desireds + i + " "
        #print desireds
        f.write(desireds)
f.close()
```

**If you want to get the output in one column.**

In above code, just replace `" "` with `"\n"` in `desireds = desireds + i + " "`

```
f = open("ms.ctl", "rb")
    s = f.read()
    f.close()

    N = s.split('\n')
    lenth = len(N)

    f = open("newms.ctl", "wb")

    for x in range(0, lenth):
            print "We're on time %d" % (x)
            spliteds = [ x for x in N[0].split('/') if x.strip()]
            desireds=""
            for i in reversed(spliteds):
                    desireds = desireds + i + "\n"
            #print desireds
            f.write(desireds)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but kindly write full function. Somehow the current format of ms.ctl  is     s= mycnf_001/mycnf_001_001      and the desired format is  mycnf_001_001 mycnf_001

Comment: (means the desired format consist of mycnf_001_001onespacemycnf_001) actually it's utterance ID followed by speaker ID

Comment: I have added the code. Hope It helps. Let us know if you see any issue.

Comment: Thanks but I need one more updation if possible, I have several hundred current formats in ms.ctl file all are as a listing format. The current code gives only one output, because it is written for a one line only, how to address current lines in the listing format, then get the output (desired format) in the list format also in single column, and then save the output in the newms.ctl file. Thanks if unclear I can explain in detail again.

Comment: You want the same result for more than 1 lines ?

Comment: Yes, like the result must be like this        mycnf_006_001 mycnf_006 
                                                               mycnf_006_002 mycnf_006
                                                                …
and finally all the thousand lines must be saved in the new file.

Comment: Above results come horizontally, i need in list wise format in a single column, some how it is not presentable here in the above comment I think you can understand (In a single column, listwise). Thanks in advance, if confused, please ask for the clear explanation

Comment: @Andy In Updated answer if you see, I had mentioned that just replace space `" "` with `"\n"` it will give you desired result. in single column.